# Xamarin.Forms save file (pdf) in local storage and open with the default viewer

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, launching-application, android-storage

**Edited to fine the question**

In Android, I need to download a pdf file to "Documents" folder and open it with the default program.
I downloaded the document and stored it in a Byte array.
Then I call this method:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Save data bytes on "My documents" folder and open
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="fileName">Filename, for example: "Test.pdf"</param>
    /// <param name="data">Array of bytes to save</param>
    /// <returns>True if success or false if error</returns>
    public bool SaveAndOpen(string fileName, byte[] data)
    {
        try
        {
            // Get my documents path
            string filePath = Path.Combine(Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath, Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDownloads);
            // Combine with filename
            string fullName = Path.Combine(filePath, fileName);

            // If the file exist on device delete it
            if (File.Exists(fullName))
            {
                // Note: In the second run of this method, the file exists
                File.Delete(fullName);
            }

            // Write bytes on "My documents"
            File.WriteAllBytes(fullName, data);

            // Launch file as process
            Process.Start(fullName);

            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ERROR: " + ex.Message + ex.StackTrace);
            return false;
        }
    }
```

The problem is to open the pdf document with the default pdf reader.

The line "Process.Start(fullName);" throws an exception

> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): Access denied

Thanks for your time!

Comment: `string filePath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
   ` Wel... which path would that be? Full path value please.

Comment: The filePath is: /data/user/0/MySampleApp.MySampleApp/files
The fullName is: /data/user/0/MySampleApp.MySampleApp/files/Test.pdf

Comment: That is in a private directory for your app only. No other app or file manager has acces. Choose another storage location for the download if you want file managers to have access.

Comment: Your right, but the question is: How to get the public My documents folder?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean with "My documents" folder. Is some file manager telling you so?

Comment: `The Process.Start line throws an "Access denied" exception: ` Which line in your code would cause that? And is the message not telling you to what -path- it is denied?

Comment: In "Process.Start(fullName);", the only one with "Process.Start" words!

Comment: With "My documents" folder I mean a folder that the user can see the document outside of my app.

Comment: Ok. Now i see. Sorry. Well that is the same reason: only your app has acces to that path. Better take a public path.

Comment: I have never seen a folder My documents and you did not tell what the user did to see that folder.

Comment: I refer to the Documents folder where the documents are stored. However, the question is where to save to open the document.

Comment: Your path is not the path of the Documents folder. And i wonder if System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) would deliver the path you mentioned.

Comment: `/storage/emulated/0/Documents` would be the path. But dont hard code that.

Comment: `I refer to the Documents folder where the documents are stored.` Documents can be stored at any place. Like images. Under My documents you will see documents from all over the place. From all storage locations of your device. Just like a Gallery app blindly shows all pictures on a device. Not only from one directory.

Comment: With "Path.Combine(Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath, Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDocuments);" I get /storage/emulated/0/Documents" but raises an exception "System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path "/storage/emulated/0/Documents/Test.pdf". I have "MANAGE_DOCUMENTS", "READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" and "WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" in the Android Manifest file

Comment: I edited the question to refine the question

Comment: DId you implement asking the user for runtime permissions? `In Android, ` Which version?

Comment: Done, saving on documents or download works, but Process.Start fails

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a way to save and open the file:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Save data bytes on "My documents" folder and open
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="fileName">Filename, for example: "Test.pdf"</param>
    /// <param name="data">Array of bytes to save</param>
    /// <returns>True if success or false if error</returns>
    public bool SaveAndOpen(string fileName, byte[] data)
    {
        try
        {
            // Get my downloads path
            string filePath = Path.Combine(Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath, Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDownloads);

            // Combine with filename
            string fullName = Path.Combine(filePath, fileName);

            // If the file exist on device delete it
            if (File.Exists(fullName))
            {
                // Note: In the second run of this method, the file exists
                File.Delete(fullName);
            }

            // Write bytes on "My documents"
            File.WriteAllBytes(fullName, data);

            // Get the uri for the saved file
            Android.Net.Uri file = Android.Support.V4.Content.FileProvider.GetUriForFile(
                this,
                this.PackageName + ".fileprovider",
                new Java.IO.File(fileName));
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView);
            intent.SetDataAndType(file, "application/pdf");
            intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearWhenTaskReset | ActivityFlags.NewTask | ActivityFlags.GrantReadUriPermission | ActivityFlags.NewTask);
            this.ApplicationContext.StartActivity(intent);

            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ERROR: " + ex.Message + ex.StackTrace);
            return false;
        }
    }
```

It's needed to request the permissions at runtime. I used Plugin.Permisions available on Nuget:

```
    Plugin.Permissions.PermissionsImplementation.Current.RequestPermissionsAsync(
         new Plugin.Permissions.Abstractions.Permission[]
         {
             Plugin.Permissions.Abstractions.Permission.Storage,
             Plugin.Permissions.Abstractions.Permission.MediaLibrary
         });
```

Also add a provider in the AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<application android:label="My app" android:icon="@mipmap/icon">
    <provider android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider" android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
    </provider>
</application>
```

In the same AndroidManifest add permisions for:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS" />
```

And add an external path in Resources/xml/file_paths.xml

```
<external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
```

Don't know if I have not needed permissions, but with this way works.

Comment: After 6 hours of surfing finally I found this answer and it solved my issue thanks. @Duefectu

Comment: any iOS version of this?

Answer (score 1):

I will extend @duefectu answer with class for reading file for more extensions
Where MainActivity.MainActivityInstance is stored MainActivityContext

```
public void Open(string path)
{
    try
    {
        var url = new Java.IO.File(path);
        var uri = FileProvider.GetUriForFile(MainActivity.MainActivityInstance,
            MainActivity.MainActivityInstance.PackageName + ".fileprovider", url);

        var intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView);
        if (url.ToString().Contains(".doc") || url.ToString().Contains(".docx"))
        {
            // Word document
            intent.SetDataAndType(uri, "application/msword");
        }
        else if (url.ToString().Contains(".pdf"))
        {
            // PDF file
            intent.SetDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf");
        }
        else if (url.ToString().Contains(".ppt") || url.ToString().Contains(".pptx"))
        {
            // Powerpoint file
            intent.SetDataAndType(uri, "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint");
        }
        else if (url.ToString().Contains(".xls") || url.ToString().Contains(".xlsx"))
        {
            // Excel file
            intent.SetDataAndType(uri, "application/vnd.ms-excel");
        }
        else if (url.ToString().Contains(".zip"))
        {
            // ZIP file
            intent.SetDataAndType(uri, "application/zip");
        }
        else if (url.ToString().Contains(".rar"))
        {
            // RAR file
            intent.SetDataAndType(uri, "application/x-rar-compressed");
        }
        else if (url.ToString().Contains(".rtf"))
        {
            // RTF file
            intent.SetDataAndType(uri, "application/rtf");
        }
        else if (url.ToString().Contains(".wav") || url.ToString().Contains(".mp3"))
        {
            // WAV audio file
            intent.SetDataAndType(uri, "audio/x-wav");
        }
        else if (url.ToString().Contains(".gif"))
        {
            // GIF file
            intent.SetDataAndType(uri, "image/gif");
        }
        else if (url.ToString().Contains(".jpg") || url.ToString().Contains(".jpeg") ||
                 url.ToString().Contains(".png"))
        {
            // JPG file
            intent.SetDataAndType(uri, "image/jpeg");
        }
        else if (url.ToString().Contains(".txt"))
        {
            // Text file
            intent.SetDataAndType(uri, "text/plain");
        }
        else if (url.ToString().Contains(".3gp") || url.ToString().Contains(".mpg") ||
                 url.ToString().Contains(".mpeg") || url.ToString().Contains(".mpe") ||
                 url.ToString().Contains(".mp4") || url.ToString().Contains(".avi"))
        {
            // Video files
            intent.SetDataAndType(uri, "video/*");
        }
        else
        {
            intent.SetDataAndType(uri, "*/*");
        }
        intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearWhenTaskReset | ActivityFlags.NewTask | ActivityFlags.GrantReadUriPermission | ActivityFlags.NewTask);
        MainActivity.MainActivityInstance.StartActivity(intent);
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        
    }
}
```