# Saving pdf to android/ios in correct way in Xamarin Forms

Tags: android, ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I Implemented in my solution custom renderers for each platform as described [here](https://www.syncfusion.com/kb/9031/how-to-save-loaded-pdf-document-in-application-level)

It works only on Android SDK 9, on version 10 of Android it shows me an exception:

> Java.IO.FileNotFoundException:
> /storage/emulated/0/TestFolder/Kiid_0380865021.pdf: open failed:
> ENOENT (No such file or directory)  - (file name and directory name is
> changed for my purposes)

Also, on iOS I have tested on iPhone 11 Pro, it apparently works, without crashing, but it saves it into some weird directory that I cant find on my phone:

/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/23278-EFS5-SGSC/Documents/Kiid_0380865021.pdf

***Expected behavior:***

**iOS:**

I want to put saved file into Downloads direcotry, or to create a new directory, which is on the root, when I go to Files..

**Android 10:**

I want to avoid crashing, and to put correct filePath.

Comment: iOS: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/file-system#sharing-with-the-files-app

Comment: Android - use DownloadManager to save files to the Downloads folder

Comment: @Jason I've read it, and I tried and nothing happens, apparently it saves somewhere, but still I cant find the file on my phone..

Comment: To save the pdf in android, try to use `File` stream to write the file to the specified path. Similar issue you could refer to:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60394507/xamarin-forms-save-file-pdf-in-local-storage-and-open-with-the-default-viewer