# Xamarin.Forms Open local PDF

Tags: pdf, xamarin.forms, xamarin.essentials

I tried to open a locally stored pdf with xamarin.

example code:

```
var files = Directory.GetFiles(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData));
var filepath = "file://" + files[0];
if (File.Exists(filepath))
{
     await Launcher.OpenAsync(filepath);
}
```

But the file does not open. The only message I get is (android device):
[image]

what do I miss?

**EDIT**

the variable filepath contains:
file:///data/user/0/com.companyname.scgapp_pdfhandler/files/.config/test.pdf

also tried

file://data/user/0/com.companyname.scgapp_pdfhandler/files/.config/test.pdf

does not help

Comment: "file://" is not a path, it is a url

Comment: Without "file://" I get the following error message Android.Content.ActivityNotFoundException: 'No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=/data/user/0/com.companyname.scgapp_pdfhandler/files/.config/test.pdf flg=0x14001000 }'

Comment: Try to pass a OpenFileRequest object instead, if you use a string it has to be the correct uri scheme for it. I suspect the uri scheme you are passing to it isn't something that is understood by the system

Comment: @guiwhatsthat I suggest you to store pdf in [external storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/files/external-storage?tabs=windows), not in [internal storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/files/) firstly. Then take a look :[open pdf with default vierer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60394507/xamarin-forms-save-file-pdf-in-local-storage-and-open-with-the-default-viewer)

Comment: @SomeStudent this was the missing part. Thanks!

Comment: @guiwhatsthat I've added my comment as an answer so that it would easier to see for other people in the future if they run into a similar issue and come across this SO post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured I would add my comment as an answer for easier visibility in case others run into it in the future.

Pass a OpenFileRequest object instead, if you use a string it has to be the correct uri scheme for it. I suspect the uri scheme you are passing to it isn't something that is understood by the system