# How to identify the Downloads folder with Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

How can I detect the "Downloads" folder in Xamarin forms? And do I need specific rights?
I cannot find a matching variable on this in GetFolderPath() nor FileSystemHelper.
Thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In android, from [external files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/files/external-storage?tabs=windows#private-external-files), we can get Downloads folder by following code:

```
 string path1 = Path.Combine(Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath, Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDownloads);
```

The path like `/storage/emulated/0/Download/`

In ios, use [this directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/file-system) to store user documents and application data files.

```
var documents = Environment.GetFolderPath (Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
```

If you want to add or modify file in Download folder, you need [request permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/permissions?tabs=windows#requesting-system-permissions) in Android platform.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

There is one thread that you can take a look:

[How to open PDF file in xamarin forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68463467/how-to-open-pdf-file-in-xamarin-forms/68466044#68466044)

Comment: Beware of the new Android 11 MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission that is needed. WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE will be completely ignored with Android 11. (With Android 10 and android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" in manifest it would still work.)

Comment: Note that Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory is deprecated in Api level 29.